# call from host to HDFS failed on connection exception java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: java, hadoop

I have started running multi node cluster in Ubuntu_16.04_LTS machine.I have two Ubuntu_18.04_LTS machines running on virtual box.
I have decided to run local machine as master and two machines on virtual box as slaves.I have made all configuration on 3 machines and started Hadoop daemons by running
1) start-dfs.sh
2) start-yarn.sh.

When I tried to access HDFS by using `hdfs dfs -ls /` command I found following exception.

`ls: Call From chinni/172.17.0.1 to chinni:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused`

where `chinni` is my machine's hostname and `172.17.0.1` is IP address.

Please provide me the solution.Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

it may caused by your `fs.defaultFS` port and `dfs.namenode.rpc-address`  port are not the same .
in **hdfs-site.xml**

```
 <property>
          <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address</name>
          <value>master:9000</value>
  </property>
```

in **core-site.xml**

```
<property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>hdfs://master:9000</value>
    </property>
```

you can change it and  reformat your cluster

Answer (score 0):

cd into your hadoop directory and start hdfs and yarn.:

```
cd $HADOOP_HOME
cd sbin
./start-dfs.sh    //Start hdfs
./start-yarn.sh   // Start yarn
```

Comment: OP said that he started the deamons, what did they do wrong starting them? Was it another way than what you recommend?